# JavaFX blur underneath area from pane

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Is there any way to add a blur effect only to a part of an image defined by the area of a Pane? If you blur the pane over the image only the pane get blurred, but is there a way to blur the picture part underneath?

Here's an example of what I mean: It's simply just an image  overlayed with a pane which has backgrouud and opacity set. Now I want to blur the part the pane lays on.

Main.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            GridPane root = (GridPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,500);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111">
  <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="495.0" fitWidth="535.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../Downloads/ZGEX2eX.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #012E56; -fx-opacity: 0.666;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Clip` of an `ImageView` to apply an effect only to a specific area of your image:

```
public class BlurredImageTest extends Application {

    private DoubleProperty effectHeight = new SimpleDoubleProperty(80);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Image image = new Image("yourImage.jpg");

        ImageView img = new ImageView(image);

        Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
        clip.widthProperty().bind(image.widthProperty());
        clip.heightProperty().bind(image.heightProperty().subtract(effectHeight));
        img.setClip(clip);

        ImageView imgEffect = new ImageView(image);

        Rectangle clipEffect = new Rectangle();
        clipEffect.widthProperty().bind(image.widthProperty());
        clipEffect.heightProperty().bind(effectHeight);
        clipEffect.translateYProperty().bind(image.heightProperty().subtract(effectHeight));

        imgEffect.setClip(clipEffect);
        imgEffect.setEffect(new GaussianBlur());

        StackPane root = new StackPane(img, imgEffect);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public final void setEffectHeight(double value) {
        effectHeight.set(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that is what I was looking for. Do you know if there is an easy way to add something like this in SceneBuilder?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to set a `Clip` in SceneBuilder.

Comment: Well then, you can't have everything.  Why would you use a clip for the unblurred image? If you don't use one, you can easily set the size and position of the blurred clip without having to worry about anything else. If you set the clip, you can only separate the image with a line. With that method, I don't think it would be possible to set the blurred part into the middle of the image